# SQL Server:exec('CALL' DB2; advice on managing result set columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, db2

Techies--

If I were issuing an openquery select, my problems would be solved--but as far as i know openquery doesn't allow the calling lingo/w. parameter(s) to remote db2 servers! :)

Here's what works:

```
declare @z varchar(max);

set @z = '999990480,888887530';

exec ('CALL S1CATALOG.HCMDEV.EMP_ALL_STARS(?)',@z) AT DB2I;
```

This stored proc (EMP_ALL_STARS) accepts the concatenated string as a clob, then returns roughly 35 columns. Not all the applcations with an interest in utilizing this sproc need all 35 columns. Any advice on how to manage the result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have control over the remote DB2 procedure? If so, you could define multiple cursors inside the proc, each with a different set of columns in the result set. At runtime, when it's time for the proc to open a cursor that performs the query and returns the result set to the caller, a bit of logic can evaluate the relevant input parameters to determine which which cursor to open.

Comment: Fred, thanks again. Great solution! Now if only I can get the developers to agree on which columns they really want!:-)

Comment: Glad to help, and there's no need to keep calling us all "techies", as we're all painfully aware of that.